# Count the number of specific words in a list

Tags: arrays, excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, array-formulas

I have some big computation to do since I have an Excel file with a column representing a list of unique IDs of people that worked on every incidents in our system. I would like to know the total number of interventions that have been done on all incidents. For example, let's say I have this:

```
ID|People working on that incident
¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯
 0|AA0000 BB1111 CC2222 ZZ1234
 1|BB1111
 2|CC2222 ZZ1234 CC2222 ZZ1234
 3|BB1111 CC2222 AA0000 BB1111
```

I have a list named *List* which has a zone with the list of people IDs I actually want to include. For example, let's say that the first zone of `List = {"AA0000","CC2222"}`.

Now, I would like to know how many interventions have been done by our employees (in *List*) on all the incidents I have (we have 4 in the array above). The result would be 6: 2 interventions for incident ID 0, 0 for ID 1, 2 for ID 2 and 2 for ID 3.

Assuming the data are in a different (closed) workbook, how can I calculate that using my list *List* and the range above A1:B4 (I would like to eventually use the whole columns, so let's say A:B)?

---

**EDIT:**

I already got something working that count the number of times a specific word is in a whole column.

```
SUM( 
    LEN('[myFile.xlsx]Sheet1'!$A:$A) 
    -LEN(
        SUBSTITUTE('[myFile.xlsx]Sheet1'!$A:$A;$Z$1;"")
        )
)
/LEN($Z$1)
```

Z1 is the word I'm looking for (example: CC2222) and `'[myFile.xlsx]Sheet1'!$A:$A` is the column I'm searching in.

Isn't there a really simple way to make this working with an array instead of Z1? The length is always the same (six plus a space).

Source: http://office.microsoft.com/en-ca/excel-help/count-the-number-of-words-in-a-cell-or-range-HA001034625.aspx

Comment: How long is your list? For short lists you could use something like `=SUM(COUNTIF(A:B,"AA0000"),COUNTIF(A:B,"CC2222"))` and you could easily replace the text strings with cell references to your list, e.g. `=SUM(COUNTIF(A:B,C1),COUNTIF(A:B,C2))` where the value in C1 is AA0000 and in C2 is CC2222, and so on. it'll get ugly if your list is very long though.

Comment: Is ```AA0000 BB1111 CC2222 ZZ1234``` one cell? I don't understand why you mention ```A:B``` and not something like ```B:E```, if this is where all people are listed.

Comment: It is all in the same cell if multiple people worked on the same incident, that's why I talked about A:B. I'm not sure `countif` works on a closed workbook but I will look into that tomorrow.

Comment: If each person was in its own separate cell, you could do it rather easily with an array formula (and I have tested one on my end that seems to work). But with those smashed into the same cell as you stated above, it will be extremely difficult if not impossible to write a viable formula without VBA.

Comment: @pnuts Yes Text to Columns would split the data but I wasn't sure if the OP really wanted the structure of his spreadsheet changed. I guess you could do a split to columns formulaically in a hidden worksheet (or anywhere really) in a range bigger than you would ever need. Then you could apply the array formula I mentioned against that range. A little messy but I think it works. Do you see any problems with that??

Comment: @pnuts Oh believe me, I completely agree with you on flat data. I have spent countless hours manipulating strangely formatted Excel tables into flat files to get them into databases. Sometimes that's just out of our control. In this case, a pivot table should work too assuming a text to columns and an unpivot as you mentioned.

Comment: I wouldn't really mind having a formula that actually split the column but that file will end up with around ~150k lines, so that would probably add up a lot to the file size. That's why the computation isn't in the same file. I don't mind if it takes 1 minute to compute (which shouldn't be the case according to some tests I made already).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally went for a completely different solution based on my working formula for 1 employee:

```
SUM( 
LEN('[myFile.xlsx]Sheet1'!$A:$A) 
-LEN(
    SUBSTITUTE('[myFile.xlsx]Sheet1'!$A:$A;$Z$1;"")
    )
)
/LEN($Z$1)
```

Instead of trying something more complicated, I just added a new column to my employee list where the total is evaluated for each employees (it was already needed elsewhere anyway). Then, I just have to sum up all the employees to get my total.

It is not as elegant as I would like and I feel like it is a workaround, but since it is the easiest solution on a programmation standpoint and that I need the individual datas anyway, it's what I really need for now.

+1 to all the other answers for your help though.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this fairly easily with a User Defined Function.  The function below takes two arguments.  The first is the range constituting you second column labelled above "People working on that incident".  The second is your List which is a range consisting of a single entry for each ID you wish to count.  As shown in your example, if multiple identical ID's are shown in a single entry (e.g. your ID 2 has CC2222 repeated twice), they will each be counted.

To enter this User Defined Function (UDF),  opens the Visual Basic Editor.
Ensure your project is highlighted in the Project Explorer window.
Then, from the top menu, select Insert/Module and
paste the code below into the window that opens.

To use this User Defined Function (UDF), enter a formula like

```
=InterventionCount(B2:B5,H1:H2)
```

in some cell.

```
Option Explicit
Function InterventionCount(myRange As Range, myList As Range) As Long
    Dim RE As Object, MC As Object
    Dim vRange As Variant, vList As Variant
    Dim sPat As String
    Dim I As Long

vRange = myRange
vList = myList

If IsArray(vList) Then
    For I = 1 To UBound(vList)
        If Not vList(I, 1) = "" Then _
        sPat = sPat & "|" & vList(I, 1)
    Next I
Else
    sPat = "|" & vList
End If
sPat = "\b(?:" & Mid(sPat, 2) & ")\b"


Set RE = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
With RE
    .Global = True
    .ignorecase = True
    .Pattern = sPat
End With

For I = 1 To UBound(vRange)
    Set MC = RE.Execute(vRange(I, 1))
    InterventionCount = InterventionCount + MC.Count
Next I

End Function
```

For a non-VBA solution you could use a helper column.  Again, List is a single column which contains the list of people you want to add up, one entry per cell.

If your data is in Column B, then add a column and enter this formula in B2:

This formula must be **array-entered**; and the $A:$J terms represent a *counter* allowing for up to ten items in the entries in column B.  If there might be more than that, expand as needed:  e.g. for up to 26 items, you would change them to $A:$Z

```
=SUM(N(TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(B2," ",REPT(" ",99)),(COLUMN($A:$J)=1)+(COLUMN($A:$J)>1)*(COLUMN($A:$J)-1)*99,99))=(List)))
```

Fill down as far as necessary, then SUM the column to get your total.

---

To **array-enter** a formula, after entering
the formula into the cell or formula bar, hold down
**ctrl-shift** while hitting **enter**.  If you did this
correctly, Excel will place braces {...} around the formula.

Comment: I would really like to avoid VBA, I know it is easier to code/understand that way but it has some other downsides since I'm not using any VBA yet.

Comment: @dnLL I'll add a non-vba solution to my answer

Comment: I'll give this a try tomorrow. The data file will end up around ~150k lines and the person who will add lines won't necessary be *good* with Excel, he's just going to copy and paste the data. I will see what I can do. VBA isn't completely out of the way since I will probably need it for something I'm planning to do, but the final computations will have to be done with formulas. If I'm using VBA, it will only be to format the data, because the person that will be using all the stats/graphes won't be a programmer. Also, VBA creates a lot of security warnings (enterprise security).

Comment: Added an edit to my post. Is there any way to make my formula working with an array instead?

Comment: @dnLL SUBSTITUTE does not accept array arguments for multiple replacements.  You would have to nest multiple arguments -- one for each name you are listing.

Answer (score 1):

Split your source data ColumnB with Text to Columns. Unpivot the result, delete the middle column and pivot what's left.